# Не запускается laravel приложение через MAMP

Tags: php, laravel, apache, mamp

Использую бесплатный MAMP

Ранее все хорошо работало, laravel приложения корректно работали через MAMP
Недавно переустановил чтоб получить новую версию php на локальном сервере и теперь при запуске laravel приложения на КАЖДОМ роуте 404 not found

При запуске через php artisan serve, все корректно запускается, но мне нужно именно через localhost мампа

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть в логах что пытается найти сервер на ваш запрос.